# Can Cycles CUDA utilize more than 2GB of VRAM?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, memory-management

I'm trying to make a render with dual Titan X's, they have 12GB of VRAM each. If I ramp the tile size up it eventually slows down seemingly due to hitting a 2GB cap?

Is there a way to have the cycles renderer utilize more than 2GB of VRAM?

Comment: I have no problems utilizing all VRAM on 780gtx 6GB, The optimal tile size for me is 512x512.

Comment: Odd, whenever I try it maxes at 2GB. I get better performance at 256x256 than 512x512 I imagine due to limited memory resources.

Comment: I need to also add that it is on win7 platform with nvidia 350.12 drivers on cuda 3.5. You may want to file a report here: https://developer.blender.org/ or search for similar.

Comment: Are you on a 32bit or 64bit system?  With 32bit systems, programs are limited to 2gb of memory, or up to 4 if they are Large Address Aware.  This limit is normally with usage of system memory, but I imagine it may apply to video memory as well.

Comment: It's a 64 bit system.

Comment: You may want to file a bug report, just to get some feedback from the core devs. I doubt they have Titan's to test, but they might have more specific information regarding drivers, etc,  for you.

Comment: I'll go ahead and do that when I have access to the system again. It's a buddies hardware.